# update using inner join from another table by recently added record

Tags: mysql

table1

```
name | value | age
--------------------
ram  | 10    | 12
ram  | 10    | 13
ram  | 12    | 14
peter| 12    | 13
peter| 14    | 15
```

table2

```
name | value | place
---------------------
john | 12    | chen
ram  | 10    | mad
peter| 12    | chen
```

So i want update table2 by recently added value from table 1
table2 have ram 10 ,peter 12. table1 recently added ram 12 and peter 14 so i want that update, thank you

Comment: Look at the [multi-table update syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) and make an attempt.

Comment: Join with a query that finds the most recent line in each group. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1